# Chef understanding only_if in execute resource

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, devops

I have here an execute block that looks like this

```
execute 'uninstall_datadog' do
  command 'sudo apt-get --purge remove datadog-agent -y'
  only_if 'command -v datadog-agent'
end
```

So my understanding is if exit status of `only_if` is not `0` then this block will not execute. Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

However I see some problems with your example:

1. the built-in `package` resource is able to remove a package if it is installed.

```
  package 'datadog-agent' do
    action :purge
    options '--yes' # not sure about this
  end
```

If the package is not installed (anymore), chef will just skip it.
 See https://docs.chef.io/resource_package.html for more details.

2. usually chef runs as root so the `sudo` command is not needed in `execute` commands.
3. `only_if` by default runs in the environment of the chef-client/chef-solo/chef-apply process. See https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#arguments you'll have to adjust environment variables like `PATH` when impersonating as another user

Comment: Nice this definitely is a better approach

Answer (score 0):

`command` is a bash builtin, looks like might not be executing as bash.
`bash -c "command -v datadog-agent"` would work, but could also use `which datadog-agent` instead.